# PushSharp - The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: pushsharp

I been searching for an answer for this for a long time now. There are a zillion discussions but none seems to have helped me (I have tried everything I have read).

I have an ASP.net website that send apple push notifications. I created a Console app using push sharp - run it on my server, the push notifications get sent/received successfully. I run the console on my local dev system, it also works. I run my 'website' from IIS Express on my local system - the push notifications are also successful. But running in IIS on my server, I am getting the dreaded 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized' - any help at this point would be fantastic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Previously, every time I have run into this issue, I have had to delete the cert out of my local machine cert store and re-import it. Then it all seems happy. I can't see how it could be a global permissions issue or invalid cert if simply re-importing it fixes the issue.

How I finally fixed it was using the [winhttpcertcfg](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19801) tool from the Windows Resource Kit to grant permission to the specific user that was using the cert.

The syntax would be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\winhttpcertcfg" -i cert.p12 -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -a UserWhoUsesTheCert -p passwordforp12
```